# shared SQLite db on windows with android applications

Tags: java, android, sqlite

**shared SQLite db on windows with android applications**

I want write application android that install on some device android
I want Center Database for all of application install
I want shared one SQLite db on windows with my Application

> I use Web Service but i want use connect to db  with IP or (local network) or other way

thank you

Answer (score 1):

I don' think you will be able to connect to remote SQLite database via socket (IP) connection from Android. Mobile data connections are not so reliable as LAN or WiFi on notebooks/PCs.

I think webService is the best solution for you. All your clients (Android apps, Windows apps) should connect to this webService.

Difference is that webService call it's just short connection (connect, send request, receive response, close connection), while database connection need to be persisted in time and can be interrupted, which may cause in inconsistent data or broken transactions.

EDIT: Other way is to use some MBasS (Mobile Backend as a Service). For example Parse.com. It could be your database and the provide their own REST API to access it.